# Why can't I remove character from the list? Also why can't I even print the element?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two problem with this code.
First, it doesn't remove the **'\n'** at the end of the list **row**.
So I tried printing **x** to see what is going on but then I ran into the second issue which is that **x** doesn't get printed. It seems that some line breaks and '51' gets printed, but why only those but not others?

**How can this happen? I have absolutely no clue.**

Edit:
This is NOT a duplicate. I want to know **why** it doesn't remove but **ALSO** why it doesn't print.
@Aran-Fey Read the question before you mark it as duplicate.

```
row = ['\n', '2017-18 ', '\n', 'GSW', '\n', '\n', '51', '\n', '32.0', '\n', '26.4', '\n', '8.4', '\n', '16.9', '\n', '49.5', '\n', '4.2', '\n', '9.8', '\n', '42.3', '\n', '5.5', '\n', '5.9', '\n', '92.1', '\n', '0.7', '\n', '4.4', '\n', '5.1', '\n', '6.1', '\n', '3.0', '\n', '1.6', '\n', '0.2', '\n', '2.2', '\n', '43.8', '\n', '5', '\n', '0', '\n', '9.5', '\n']

i = 0
for x in row:
  print(i,":", x)
  if x in ('\n', '°', '%'):
    row.remove(x)
  i+=1
print(row)
```

The output of this is

```
0 : 

1 : 

2 : 

3 : 51
4 : 

5 : 

6 : 

7 : 

8 : 

9 : 

10 : 

11 : 

12 : 

13 : 

14 : 

15 : 

16 : 

17 : 

18 : 

19 : 

20 : 

21 : 

22 : 

23 : 

24 : 

25 : 

26 : 

27 : 

['2017-18 ', 'GSW', '51', '32.0', '26.4', '8.4', '16.9', '49.5', '4.2', '9.8', '42.3', '5.5', '5.9', '92.1', '0.7', '4.4', '5.1', '6.1', '3.0', '1.6', '0.2', '2.2', '43.8', '5', '0', '9.5', '\n']
```

You can run this code here: https://repl.it/@leonardchoo/listnotworking

Comment: you should never modify an object as you iterate through it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis why?

Comment: @Aran-Fey This question is not a duplicate of what you provided. Please remove the duplicate sign. Read the question before you mark it as duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how it's not a duplicate. Removing elements from a list while iterating makes the loop skip some of the elements. It's all explained in the question I linked.

Comment: There, I found a better dupe.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, that new link makes sense. If you read my question carefully, there are two problems: 1. can't remove 2. can't print. Your new link still doesn't answer the 2nd part. That means that is only 50% of the duplicate. Hence if you mark it as duplicate, my question might not get enough attention for full answers. If it is not a full duplicate please don't mark it as one since it doesn't help me in any ways. Instead include that in the comment saying "this is the possible duplicate of..."

Comment: *It doesn't get printed because the loop skips some elements.* It's exactly the same reason why it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @Aran-Fey now THAT is understandable. These things may be obvious to you, but please keep in mind that it's not obvious to everyone, especially beginners. If you post it as the answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
row = ['\n', '2017-18 ', '\n', 'GSW', '\n', '\n', '51', '\n', '32.0', '\n', '26.4', '\n', '8.4', '\n', '16.9', '\n', '49.5', '\n', '4.2', '\n', '9.8', '\n', '42.3', '\n', '5.5', '\n', '5.9', '\n', '92.1', '\n', '0.7', '\n', '4.4', '\n', '5.1', '\n', '6.1', '\n', '3.0', '\n', '1.6', '\n', '0.2', '\n', '2.2', '\n', '43.8', '\n', '5', '\n', '0', '\n', '9.5', '\n']

row = [x for x in row if x not in ['\n', '°', '%']]

for i, x in enumerate(row):
    print(i, x)
```

**Output**

```
0 2017-18
1 GSW
...
23 5
24 0
25 9.5
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why my code can't remove and can't print?

Comment: better to remove and create another `list` not to modify old one when you iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

row = ['\n', '2017-18 ', '\n', 'GSW', '\n', '\n', '51', '\n', '32.0', '\n', '26.4', '\n', '8.4', '\n', '16.9', '\n', '49.5', '\n', '4.2', '\n', '9.8', '\n', '42.3', '\n', '5.5', '\n', '5.9', '\n', '92.1', '\n', '0.7', '\n', '4.4', '\n', '5.1', '\n', '6.1', '\n', '3.0', '\n', '1.6', '\n', '0.2', '\n', '2.2', '\n', '43.8', '\n', '5', '\n', '0', '\n', '9.5', '\n']
removeElement=["\n",'°','%']
for i in list(row):
    if i in removeElement:
        row.remove(i)
print(row)